# Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a problem trying to configure postrgres with nodeJs, i followed this [tutorial](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/) and i get a error that doesn't specify anything about what is wrong:

here is the **stacktrace**

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
    at C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1976:15
    at Array.map (native)
    at conformOptions (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1941:39)
    at Model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:700:7)
    at Model.tryCatcher (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:577:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAtPostResolution (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:244:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:128:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

my model:

```
var express = require('express');
var models = require('../models');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var User = models.User;
  User.findById(1).then(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

**my router:**

"use strict";

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return User;
};
```

Comment: ur link to the tutorial doesn't work

Comment: well page down s:/

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Is posible that you have a problem with the depth of your model path, check first if that is the correct path. Alternatively, you can manage your require imports as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520), it will result really handy and useful.

Answer (score 0):

`models` exports a function with the parameters `(sequelize, DataTypes)`, yet it is invoked without bring provided parameters. You first need to invoke your models function with the right parameters, and then assign the returned models to variables. Ugliest case, you could write:

`var User = models(sequelize, DataTypes).User;`

...after having initialized `sequelize` and `DataTypes` in your router.  But you should probably do that in the models file and restructure that file to have an initializer.