# Sequelize.js: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I'm using Sequelize.js in my Node.js application and keep running into a very strange problem.

**Background:** I have two models, *Account* and *AccountCategory* as follows. My API endpoint calls the route `/accounts` which calls the accounts controller to do an `Account.findAll()` query.

*Accounts* model has a `defaultScope` to include the related category by default, without having to specify it each time inside the `findAll({})` block.

**Problem:** When the *Accounts* model is attempting to access and return the data from the database, the `defaultScope` is trying to include the *AccountCategory*, Sequelize throws the error:

> Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.

I suspect it has to do with the fact that *AccountCategory* is placed after *Account* in my *models* folder when the models are being set up and thus not processed (associated). I base this on the fact that other associations like *User* and *Role* (ie. a user has a role) are fine using the same method (ie. no problem with path depth as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938411/include-unexpected-element-has-to-be-either-a-model-an-association-or-an-objec) suggests).

I've spent the last 2 days trying to get the `defaultScope` working and stop producing this error without any luck. Similar questions do not provide an answer and I would greatly appreciate any help resolving this problem. Thanks.

**Account:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Account = sequelize.define(
        "Account",
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(100)
            },
            category_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false
            }
        },
        {
            timestamps: false,
            tableName: "Account",
            defaultScope: {
                include: [{
                    model: sequelize.models.AccountCategory,
                    as: "category"
                }]
            }
        }
    );

    Account.associate = models => {
        // Association: Account -> AccountCategory
        Account.belongsTo(models.AccountCategory, {
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            foreignKey: {
                fieldName: "category_id",
                allowNull: false,
                require: true
            },
            targetKey: "id",
            as: "category"
        });
    };

    return Account;
};
```

**Account Category:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var AccountCategory = sequelize.define(
        "AccountCategory",
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true
            }
        },
        {
            timestamps: false,
            tableName: "Account_Category"
        }
    );

    return AccountCategory;
};
```

**Models Index:**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASS,
    {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: "mysql",
        operatorAliases: false,

        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }
    }
);

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (
            file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
        );
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
    db[modelName].associate(db);
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Are you certain about the sequence of your code?  I.e. should be both define() statements, then associate(), then findAll()?  Similar code works for me...

Comment: I am, could you try renaming the model you attempt to include, to make it appear before the one referencing it? Just want to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Turns out to be painful for me to try that.  Can't you do this yourself, e.g. replace the readDir with `var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, 'account.js'));
        db[model.name] = model;model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, 'account_categoryjs'));
        db[model.name] = model;`   (or, whatever order you want?)

Comment: I am having the same problem, which I can confirm is being caused by import / sequencing order performed in the models `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you say:

> I suspect it has to do with the fact that AccountCategory is placed after Account in my models folder when the models are being set up and thus not processed (associated).

**TLDR:** Add a new function to your model class definition similar to the `associate` function, and use the [addScope](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-addScope) function to define any scopes that reference other models that may have not been initialized due to file tree order. Finally, call that new function the same way you call `db[modelName].associate` in your `models.index.js` file.

I had a similar problem and solved it by defining any scopes that reference any models, e.g. in an `include`, after all the models are initialized after running the following in your `models/index.js` file.

Here is an example:

**models/agent.js**

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
const camelCase = require('lodash/camelCase');
const { permissionNames } = require('../../api/constants/permissions');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  /**
   * @summary Agent model
   */
  class Agent extends Model {}

  Agent.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      scopes: {
        // Works because the agent-role.js file / model comes before agent.js in the file tree
        [camelCase(permissionNames.readAgentRoles)]: {
          include: [
            {
              model: sequelize.models.AgentRole,
            },
          ],
        },
        // Doesn't work due to import order in models/index.js, i.e., agent.js is before role.js in the file tree
        // [camelCase(permissionNames.readRoles)]: {
        //   include: [
        //     {
        //       model: sequelize.models.Role,
        //     },
        //   ],
        // },
      },
    }
  );

  Agent.associate = function (models) {
    Agent.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
      through: 'AgentRole',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE', // default for belongsToMany
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE', // default for belongsToMany
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'agentId',
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
    Agent.hasMany(models.AgentRole, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'agentId',
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  };

  // Add a custom `addScopes` function to call after initializing all models in `index.js`
  Agent.addScopes = function (models) {
    Agent.addScope(camelCase(permissionNames.readRoles), {
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Role,
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  return Agent;
};
```

**models/index.js**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const config = require('../database-config.js');
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

/**
 * Import and attach all of the model definitions within this 'models' directory to the sequelize instance.
 */
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js';
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    // Here is where file tree order matters... the sequelize const may not have the required model added to it yet
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
  // We need to add scopes that reference other tables once they have all been initialized
  if (db[modelName].addScopes) {
    db[modelName].addScopes(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Goodluck!